# Glmer two measurements, two groups, gamma distribution

Tags: lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, gamma-distribution

i wondered whether this is the right approach for my data.
I have two groups that completed a questionnaire twice (so two measurements for each subject).
My data kinda looks like this:

```
id   group  time   item1   item2  item3   sum
1    a      1       1       0      1       2
1    a      2       1       0      1       2
2    b      1       1       0      0       1
2    b      2       1       0      0       1
3    a      1       0       1      1       2
3    a      2       0       1      1       2
```

Because sums are always positive and not normally distributed I thought of using a generalized linear model with gamma distribution (`glm`).
And because I have repeated measures I thought a mixed model would make sense.

Thus, I would use a generalized linear mixed model with following formula:

```
glmer(score ~ group + time + group*time + (1|id), family = Gamma)
```

Does this make sense ?

Would be very grateful for any comment! Thanks in advance!!w

Comment: A Gamma distribution, which describes a continuous response, scarcely seems appropriate for a discrete response having few values with nonzero probability.  Why aren't you considering discrete distributions like the Binomial?  As far as a mixed model goes, that looks like a good consideration, but one then wonders how you ought to model "group" and "time": what is the experimental design and what are you trying to estimate?

Comment: Thank you, I rethought that one and came up with a negative binomial distribution or poisson distribution (because "sum" can only be positive).  The design is simple. There are two groups which completed a questionnaire two times (pre and post the same treatment). The hypothesis is that sum will be higher at time point two in group a than in group b/ or that the probability is higher to have a higher score at time point two when you are in group a. @whuber